# Xclass of localRecordList - is there a way in TYPO3 8.7?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In an ancient installation (version 4.5) I used a xclass of `localRecordList` (`class.ux_db_list_extra.inc`) in order to change the csv export in list mode (e.g. changing the separation sign to `;`). Is there a possibility in TYPO3 8.7 to achieve the same? I need an Excel compatible csv file with `;` as separator and latin instead of utf8.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the docs https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Xclasses/Index.html

It's still possible but registration changed